# UIScrollView with an imageview detecting touch

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView and inside that one image view. The imageview must draw on response to user touches on the image view. But it must scroll and zoom the image on swipe and pinch gesture. How can i enable both these functionalities at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement UIScrollViewDelegate

```
-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
```

And enable user interaction on your UIImageView

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Then to detect swipes you can use UISwipeGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Does any one has got solution to this problem i am having same problem and not able to implement it